# Mongo collection lock in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, locking

In Nodejs How to lock a mongodb collection for query and update then release lock.

My documents will be like this.
`{
    _id:1,
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "x1" : 0.5
}`

This is my code

```
lockCollectionUntilCompleteThisFunction(db, 2, "col1", function () {
});

function lockCollectionUntilCompleteThisFunction(db, n, col, callback) {
    db.collection(col).findOne({x1: 1}, function (err, doc) {
        if (!err) {
            var a = doc.a;
            var b = doc.b + n;
            var x1 = a / b;
            var updateDoc = {
                b: b,
                x1: x1
            }
            db.collection(col).updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: updateDoc}, function (err) {
                if (!error) {
                    callback(null);
                }
                else {
                    callback(err)
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
}
```

So, My need is while executing this function it should lock the collection. How can I achieve that.

Comment: why you need to lock full collection?

Comment: I want no other process use this "x1" field in between my find query and update query.